# Generating dll for deploying

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

When I publish my asp .net mvc 4 using the File system method but the System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll and System.Web.Http.dll are not generated. Yesterday, everything worked fine and I succeded to generate all dll and publish the app. Anyone know what can cause this problem?

Comment: Once clear your prefatch data, with typing `prefetch` on `Run` and clear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem here.
Maybe it's because of Microsoft Security Update for MVC? This update was installed automatically yesterday on my PC and since then 3 DLLs (including System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll) were missing in deployment.

Updating Nuget Package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi to 5.2.2 helped...

Comment: Thank you it worked. Hard to guess that an automatic update will create problem in deploying

Answer (score 2):

Set the dll's to copy to local:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx

or more comprehensively, on the target server install any non-bin dependencies.
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/data-access/details/manually-installing-references-required-by-the-web-api-service